# How to convert or merge multiple assert statements into one

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, assert

I have a multiple assert statement in a python test function as below:

```
def test_function():
    assert A.a == 1
    assert B.b == 2
    assert C.c == 3
    assert D.d == 4
    assert E.e == 5
    assert F.f == 6
    assert G.g == 7
```

I just want to write this test function in a proper dynamic way, so I have tried:

```
import unittest
def test_function():
    x = {"a": A.a, "b": B.b, "c": C.c, "d": D.d, "e": E.e, "f":F.f, "g":G.g}
    y = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f":6, "g":7}
    for k, v in x.items():
        for k1, v1 in y.items():
            if k == k1 and v==v1:
                assert v == v1
```

But I have found that is also not a good way, because `"if"` is not required, but if I remove the "if" statement an error occurs.

I'm looking for a better way to merge this `assert` statements.

---

**EDIT:** Simply I can put all `A.a, B.a....` and `1, 2, ..` in the list like below,

```
l1 = [A.a, B.b, C.c, D.d, E.e, F.f, G.g]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And from it want to make assert statement,

```
assert l1[0] == l2[0]
assert l1[1] == l2[1].......
```

**without any inbuilt function**

Comment: You can just use `and`: `assert A.a == 1 and B.b == 2 and ...`. Any better suggestions to refactor would require more context about where your values are coming from

Comment: (By better, I don't mean just doing something like `observed = [A.a, B.b, ..]; expected = [1,2,...]; assert all(map(operator.eq, observed, expected))`.)

Comment: what is `operator.eq`. can you please add your answer

Comment: It's in the `operator` module, basically an efficient version of `lambda x, y: x == y`.

Comment: so to use, how can I make it available.

Comment: You import it; it's in the standard library, no additional packages need to be installed.

Comment: Getting assertion error, 
`def test_demo():
        observed = ["A", "B"]
        expected = [1,2]
>       assert all(map(operator.eq, observed, expected))
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = all(<map object at 0x00000248C262E3D0>)
E        +    where <map object at 0x00000248C262E3D0> = map(<built-in function eq>, ['A', 'B'], [1, 2])
E        +      where <built-in function eq> = operator.eq

test.py:6: AssertionError`

Comment: That's because you didn't define `observed` correctly. You want to compare `A.a` to `1`, not `"A"`.

Comment: Edit the question, please have look in edit part

Comment: "Without any inbuilt function" Why?

Comment: is it possible using for loop?

Comment: Of course: `for o, e in zip(observed, expected): assert o == e`.

Comment: is there any way to do it without any in-built function ? (just asking for alternative way)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `unittest`, you need to put your test in a class which extends `unittest.TestCase`. Then you can use the `assertEqual()` method from `unittest.TestCase`:

```
import unittest

def MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_function(self):
        x = {"a": A.a, "b": B.b, "c": C.c, "d": D.d, "e": E.e, "f":F.f, "g":G.g}
        y = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f":6, "g":7}
        self.assertEqual(x, y)
```

On the other hand, if you are using `pytest`, you can just `assert x == y`:

```
def test_function():
    x = {"a": A.a, "b": B.b, "c": C.c, "d": D.d, "e": E.e, "f":F.f, "g":G.g}
    y = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f":6, "g":7}
    assert x == y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the test in a *proper dynamic way* without using the Python `unittest` you can use the following `test_function()`:

```
def test_function():
    l1 = [A.a, B.b, C.c, D.d, E.e, F.f, G.g]
    l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    for i in range(0, len(l1)):
        assert l1[i] == l2[i]
```

Previous code use the list `l1` and `l2` defined in the edited part of your question.

Furthermore I think that use of the `unittest` module is preferable and in this case you can refer to the @Code-Apprentice 's answer.